# C# ContextMenuStrip assign at runtime

Tags: c#, visual-studio

C# - in my application I have three seperate `contextSensitiveMenus`

1. **popUpGuests**
2. **popUpPeople**
3. **popUpStatements**

At run time I want to select which `popUp menu` is used depending certain conditions.  I can find a whole lot online about creating `contextSensitiveMenus` at run time but nothing about selecting from a choice of "predefined" menus.

> I've been fiddling with: txtText.ContextMenuStrip... but can't get it
>   to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm still not clear about your problem and what do you mean by `Predefined` menus. still, have you tried to put all the Menu options in one context menu, and setting visibility of their according to your run time conditions ?

Comment: Predefined means that each of the contextSensitiveMenus is fully poplulated at design time.  Making items visible or not may work but there are so many for each of them that I thought it easier to create three seperate ones.

Comment: you can set a `Tag` property of each menu options (which should be unique - you can use Enum for that), when user selects any option, you can check tag and determine which option has been selected. But I'm sure there will more sophisticated solution for this problem. It will be easier for us if you provide some working code and you point out where exactly you need help.

Comment: There is a bug in the code that assigns the ContextMenuStrip property, but you don't show us.  Just don't tinker with it and get it right at the exact moment the mouse button is clicked.  Use the control's MouseUp event.  If e.Button is the right button then use the Show() method of the context menu you want.

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming you have problem in deciding which option has been selected form which context menu.*

As I've mentioned in comment, I'm posting a working sample code here for your better understanding.

First you have to make an enumeration representing all possible menu options of your context menu. We will use it to tag menu options uniquely.
(you can avoid this by simply tagging a `string`, but enum is easy and clean to work with)

Suppose you have following options.

```
    public enum contextMenuOptions
    {
        guestOption1,
        guestOption2,
        guestOption3,
        peopleOption1,
        peopleOption2,
        peopleOption3,
        statOption1,
        statOption2,
        statOption3
    }
```

while initializing your 'predefined' menu options you can tag them with this enum like below. And also, you can set created `ContextMenuStrip` to particular `TextBox`

```
        ContextMenuStrip popUpGuest = new ContextMenuStrip();

        ToolStripTextBox guestMenuitem1 = new ToolStripTextBox();
        guestMenuitem1.Text = "Guest Option1";
        guestMenuitem1.Tag = contextMenuOptions.guestOption1; //tagging with enum
        guestMenuitem1.Click += Menuitem_Click;
        popUpGuest.Items.Add(guestMenuitem1);

        txtGuest.ContextMenuStrip = popUpGuest;
```

same way for other options and other context menus

```
        ContextMenuStrip popUpPeople = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripTextBox peopleMenuitem1 = new ToolStripTextBox();
        peopleMenuitem1.Text = "people option1";
        peopleMenuitem1.Tag = contextMenuOptions.peopleOption1;
        peopleMenuitem1.Click += Menuitem_Click;
        popUpPeople.Items.Add(peopleMenuitem1);
        txtPeople.ContextMenuStrip = popUpPeople;
```

and

```
        ContextMenuStrip popUpStatement = new ContextMenuStrip();
        ToolStripTextBox stateMenuitem1 = new ToolStripTextBox();
        stateMenuitem1.Text = "stat Option1";
        stateMenuitem1.Tag = contextMenuOptions.statOption1;
        stateMenuitem1.Click += Menuitem_Click;
        popUpStatement.Items.Add(stateMenuitem1);
        txtStatement.ContextMenuStrip = popUpStatement;
```

note that click handler for all options is common `Menuitem_Click`, thus no matter which option is selected form which context menu, this handler will be called. And here we will put general solution.

```
    void Menuitem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ToolStripTextBox senderMenuItem = (ToolStripTextBox)sender;
        contextMenuOptions tag = (contextMenuOptions)senderMenuItem.Tag;

        TextBox textBoxToBeUpdated = null;

        string optionSelected = "";
        switch (tag)
        {
            case contextMenuOptions.guestOption1:
                optionSelected = "guestOption1";
                textBoxToBeUpdated = txtGuest;
                break;
            case contextMenuOptions.guestOption2:
                optionSelected = "guestOption2";
                textBoxToBeUpdated = txtGuest;
                break;
            case contextMenuOptions.guestOption3:
                optionSelected = "guestOption3";
                textBoxToBeUpdated = txtGuest;
                break;
            case contextMenuOptions.peopleOption1:
                optionSelected = "PeopleOption1";
                textBoxToBeUpdated = txtPeople;
                break;
            case contextMenuOptions.statOption1:
                optionSelected = "StatmentOption1";
                textBoxToBeUpdated = txtStatement;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        textBoxToBeUpdated.Text = optionSelected;
    }
```

Comment: @TKO yes, that will set particular ContextMenuStrip to txtText 's right click drop down. is this what you were looking for ? I've updated my answer